# Select the country whose sum of population is 80% of total population of whole country

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table of 25590 rows and 2 column which has

```
Country|Population
A|1234
A|2134
B|2342
B|2193
```

like this there are 30 country and we have to calculate top populated countries which will occupy 80% population of all the country together. for example

```
population of A+population of B +......+population of N must be 80% of total population of country added together.
```

For that I tried these method

```
SELECT distinct
    country,
    population,
    PERCENT_RANK() OVER (
        PARTITION BY country
        ORDER BY population desc
    )
FROM 
    public.age_specific_notification_rate;
```

From this way neither I could sort the population nor I could calculate sum of each country.
Then i tried this way

```
select distinct country,sum(population) 
from public.age_specific_notification_rate
group by country,population
```

This way I couldn't get distinct country with total sum of one country.

Method I tried is so far from desired result. Please help me solve it

Comment: This is not clear. Lets say a country has a population of 100,000. What exactly are you trying to return? A country is a country. If you want to find the oldest 80% of the people, that's doable. But you are simply saying you want 80% of the country?????I suspect you are trying to get 80% of the TOTAL population (ie, all countries added together). I recommend editing your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
WITH running_sum AS
  (
    SELECT Country, SUM(tot_pop) OVER (ORDER BY tot_pop DESC) / SUM(tot_pop) OVER () rs
    FROM
     (
       SELECT Country, SUM(Population) tot_pop
       FROM age_specific_notification_rate
       GROUP BY Country
     ) T
  )
SELECT Country, rs FROM running_sum WHERE TRUNC(rs,1) <= 0.8
```

The inner query finds the sum of the population for each country, and the outer query finds the [running sum](https://learnsql.com/blog/what-is-a-running-total-and-how-to-compute-it-in-sql/) of the population for the countries ordered by their `SUM(Population)` from high to low.

`SUM(tot_pop) OVER (ORDER BY tot_pop DESC)` is used to calculate the running sum of `tot_pop` for all countries starting from the country with the highest `tot_pop`.

`SUM(tot_pop) OVER ()` is used to find the total sum of `tot_pop` for all countries.

By dividing the running sum by the total sum you get the percentage of the population (up to the current row) over the total sum of the population for all countries. Note that we used `ORDER BY tot_pop DESC` to calculate the running sum and this will guarantee that countries with the highest population are included first.

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/rUcux4Z_).

Comment: It's right but couldn't understand the logic behind
 "SUM(tot_pop) OVER (ORDER BY tot_pop DESC) / SUM(tot_pop) OVER ()". What exactly it do?

Comment: Added an extra explanation, I hope this helps.